# filter columns which have significant difference

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have column around and for each id there is one min column and max column with same id. As you can see in the screenshot. So my desired requirement is from all the column I have, I only want to pick column which have pretty less significant difference in value and if value is np.nan or 0.0 it should not give importance to those, only value. Because data is very sparse.
[image]

To Create DF:

```
df = {'brand_no':['BH 1', 'BH 2', 'BH 5', 'BH 6', 'BH 6'],
       '1240000601_min':[5.87,5.67,6.9,1.0,np.nan],
       '1240000601_max':[8.87,7.47,10.1,1.9,10.8],
      '1240000603_min':[5.87,np.nan,6.5,2.0,7.8],
       '1240000603_max':[8.57,7.47,10.2,1.0,10.2],
      '1240000604_min':[5.87,5.67,6.9,1.0,7.8],
       '1240000604_max':[8.87,7.47,0.0,np.nan,10.1],
      '1240000605_min':[15.87,15.67,16.9,1.0,17.8],
       '1240000605_max':[18.11,17.47,20.1,1.9,22.6],
      '1240000606_min':[8.12,5.67,6.9,np.nan,7.8],
       '1240000606_max;':[np.nan,7.47,10.1,1.9,np.nan]}
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
# Print the output.
df
```

Desired output:
[image]

Explanation :
As we can see 1240000605_min and 1240000605_max the only columns get filtered out because. If we look at the values they have and for all others columns, this id is the only id having value very far from other columns value.

Comment: How do you want to define "significant difference"? For example, 5%, 10%, 20% away from the mean?

Comment: @not_speshal around 30-40%

Comment: @not_speshal around 40% of their median.

Comment: For your example, row 4 of 1240000605_min and 1240000605_max (1 and 1.9) are within 40% of your median. So not sure how you're filtering that out.

Comment: @not_speshal I am just printing that by creating df excluding that column which is very far in our case 1240000605_min and 1240000605_max. I need the code for that only.

Comment: What I'm saying is row 4 of 1240000605_min and 1240000605_max are NOT "very far"

Answer (score 0):

I would probably work with the "_min" and "_max" columns separately and `concat` them after filtering.
Assuming your criteria is to only have values within 40% of the median, this works:

```
min_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if "min" in c]]
max_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if "max" in c]]

result = pd.concat([min_df[abs(min_df.div(min_df.median(axis=1), axis=0)-1)<0.3],
                    max_df[abs(max_df.div(max_df.median(axis=1), axis=0)-1)<0.3]], axis=1)
result = result[df.columns.intersection(result.columns)]
```

The last line just reorganizes the column order to match the original DataFrame.

Comment: Hey @not_speshal, I applied the the code on above df, it returning as it is its not filtering out the column which have value far from their median

Comment: Even if I change 0.3 to 0.7 or 0.9 it returns all the columns

Comment: Like it said, in your example, no rows meet the criteria you specified. Specifically, 1240000605_min and 1240000605_max in row 3 (the first row with brand_no BH6) are within all criteria.